# how to call SWF Files in an android app on Android Device

Tags: android

i want to call swf file in android apps like html hyper link with another page
i am new to make android apps...please help me..

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class SWFViewer extends Activity {
WebView wvswf;
LinearLayout linearLayout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_swfviewer);
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    wvswf = new WebView(SWFViewer.this);
    wvswf.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wvswf.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    wvswf.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    linearLayout.addView(wvswf, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

String Url = "file:///android_asset/main.swf";
wvswf.loadUrl(Url);

    }
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also facing the same problem last week and I solved it following way.

Move to your menifest file,
Set `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in your application tag and also to the activity in which you've placed your webview.

Other thing which you need to do is download and install flash player apk from [this link](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html?PID=3640929)

Now your webview code will work and .swf files can be played inside webview.

**P.S:** download flashplayer apk for android 4.0 devices for ics and above from the given link.

If you are unable to install the apk then go to settings--->security---->Check "Unkown sources option".

You can find the complete code [here](http://pastie.org/8710931)

Hope this Helps to you.

Comment: thanks for give your time. can you send me this application which can call swf file... with source code..

Comment: @debid wait for a while please

Comment: @debid see edited answer and mark this as answer if it works for you.

Comment: can you send me full source code with running in my email id @devendranegi121@gmail.com   i am waiting for your response..thanks

Comment: After run this apps give  error ---- unfortunately, swf_android has stopped.